# How to exclude some properties of ModelDriven Action from being updated in Struts 2

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, aspectj, aop

We are using an action with `ModelDriven` interface. The action has the [`scopedModelDriven` interceptor](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/scoped-model-driven-interceptor.html) and we save the model in session.

The model is as below:

```
public class Fundtransfer{

private String amount;
private String sourceAccount;
private String destinationAccount;
private String sign

//setter's and getter's ommited
}
```

The `Fundtransfer` bean is used as a model. The JSP form has amount, `sourceAcount` and `destinationAcount` fields which maps to `Fundtransfer` bean automatically via `modelDriven` interceptor.
Every thing is normal till hear!

Of course the user can simple tramped the HTML form and pass a variable named  `sign` to the action and the interceptor will update it the bean.

Is it possible that we can configure a model in away that the sign value could not be updated via `ModelDriven` interceptor.

I know I can create a new bean and then copy it to `Fundtransfer` bean or use some sort of inheritance. Are there better ways.

The real bean which we are using is huge and also some of the has nested beans.

I thought may be I can use some aspect tricks but I don't know is it possible or not?

Comment: You should **not** expose values that should not be set via setters. This is generally very dangerous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ModelDriven` bean usually used for read/write via the getters/setters. You can control access here. However, if you don't know yet Struts2 set parameters via [`params` interceptor](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/parameters-interceptor.html) which uses OGNL to populate the model. You can control this interceptor via parameters `excludeParams` for example

```
<interceptor-ref name="params">
  <param name="excludeParams">
    dojo\..*,^struts\..*,sign
  </param>
</interceptor-ref>
```

Another approach is to use `ParameterNameAware` where you could implement black/white list of parameters. Be careful with this approach can open door to restricted parameters by the first method.

Comment: Thanks. Do you mean even if I use ParameterNameAware, there me be an open door in my application?!